# Is there a standard for writing the beginning comments of a matlab file?

Tags: matlab, comments

Is there a conventional format for writing the beginning description of a matlab file?

Such as including author(s), version number, last revised on, etc.

When I search for this all I find is info on [comments themselves](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comments.html?searchHighlight=matlab%20comments) or for [commenting the help text for functions](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/30/commenting-code/).

**EDIT:** 
To clarify, I was wondering if there is a place to put authorship details of an entire simulation for example? I.e: Text that is not the function description / help text (which is also very useful and thank you all for providing details on that).

On mathworks I found info about the [Contents.m file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-help-summary-contents-m.html). When used, it provides a summary of the program files, and version number. Have any of you used this file for including extra details such as authorship, location, etc?

I was basically just thinking about other conventions such as in Java (I don't mean to compare the two, but just for added clarification of what I was looking for):

```
/**
* The Foo program displays Hello World!
*
* @author  J Smith  << A place to put these details?
* @version 1.0
* @since   2016-08-23
*/
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

While there is no strict standard for the *contents* of the beginning comments of your functions (i.e. the ["Help text"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-help-for-your-program.html)), there are some specific things you should know about their *format* that determine how MATLAB will use or display them. Let's start with this sample:

```
function c = addme(a,b)
% ADDME  Add two values together.  <---- H1 line
%   C = ADDME(A) adds A to itself.
%   C = ADDME(A,B) adds A and B together.
%
%   See also SUM, PLUS.

% Some other comment...

switch nargin
  case 2
    c = a + b;
  case 1
    c = a + a;
  otherwise
    c = 0;
end
```

**1) The H1 line:** This is the very first comment line, and this is what will get displayed by the Current Folder browser or the [`lookfor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lookfor.html) command. When using the [`lookfor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lookfor.html) command, this is the only part of the first comment block that is searched by default. You have to add the `-all` option for the entire help comment block to be searched. Therefore, it's generally a good idea to put key descriptive words here to aid people searching for functions related to some operation.

**2) The [`help`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/help.html) command:** The entire first contiguous block of comments in your function will be displayed when using the [`help`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/help.html) command. For the above sample, `help addme` will show all the comments up to and including the 'See also ...' line, but will not show the 'Some other comment...' line.

**3) Hyperlinking to other functions:** If you'd like to include hyperlinks to related functions in your help text, you can add the line `% See also` to the end of your help text followed by the names of these functions. For the above sample, typing `help addme` will display the help text with links for the `sum` and `plus` functions, and clicking these links will in turn display the help text for those functions.

Other than these few considerations, it's up to you to determine what your help text should contain. I generally err on the side of "more is better". :)

Answer (score 1):

Matlab does not enforce one, but it *does* have one, and provides a basic example here: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-help-for-your-program.html

A useful command to help you check if you've added appropriate documentation is `helprpt`. If you're missing a help header, or your help header is missing `examples` / `see also` syntax etc, it will tell you. **EDIT: This has been replaced by graphical menus in 2016a; see [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-which-programs-have-help.html). Also have a look at [codetools](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-help-summary-contents-m.html)**.

Furthermore, Octave defines [something similar](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Format-of-Descriptions.html#Format-of-Descriptions) in the octave manual, as well as some useful guidelines on [coding style in general](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Octave-Sources-_0028m_002dfiles_0029.html#Octave-Sources-_0028m_002dfiles_0029); (I find this style to be very tidy and I recommend it).

In general, both in matlab and in octave, a consistent style is maintained throughout all their m-files; if you open any m-file from the distribution and imitate the style, you'll get it right.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no "official" / "universal" standard. You can pick any convention you want, or roll out your own. Once you decide how you want your comments to look like, it's a good idea to be consistent and stick to it.

Usually, at least for most build-in functions, you will find 1. a short description, followed by 2. the usage syntax, 3. a more comprehensive description and 4. related functions.

Comment: There *is* an official standard, and matlab even provides a tool to detect inconsistencies and help you write appropriate help headers consistent with the Mathworks standard. But obviously it does not enforce this style.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far to call help guidelines a standard (considering the items asked by the OP), but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Fair enough, yes. It's a matter of definition, I guess. My feeling is that it's a "standard" in the sense that some functionality relies on it being followed (e.g. `lookfor`, `help`, `see also`, links, copyright and versionstrings etc all expect a specific format in order to function), as opposed to "guidelines" which is just a matter of aesthetics (e.g. the [octave coding guidelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Octave-Sources-_0028m_002dfiles_0029.html#Octave-Sources-_0028m_002dfiles_0029)).

Answer (score 0):

To see an example run this command in MATLAB:

```
edit fft
```

By the way, as @DanielG said there is no official/universal standard.

Comment: The `fit` example requires the Curve Fitting Toolbox. Better use the core function `fft`.

Comment: correct! `edit fit` requires the Curve fitting Toolbox.